# Adding Facebook as a Share button for iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, button, shared

I don't understand in order to create a Facebook share button is it a MUST to download their SDK, and get a Facebook App ID, then link App ID to .plist file and then link FBSDKShareKit.framework to project  OR can I just use the social.framework and link that to project and use the following code...

```
 if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:@"high score is %i"];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

Doing it this way with social framework and the above code works fine. Or is it a MUST to add the Facebook SDK and get a App ID with a Facebook developer account and all that?

If I do it the social.framework way instead of using the Facebook SDK and Facebook App-ID would my app get rejected and would I have a problem with Facebook company?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a must to do it the SDK way, but it is recommended. Also your app won't be rejected for that, I guess.

The SDK way offers you much more functionalities regarding the Social framework. By using it and linking with an App ID you could track all the Insights regarding the activity of your users with FB, request permission to get some data from their FB profiles and link it among your other apps and maybe a FB page, FB login...

Comment: I made a simple game. I'm only looking for users to share their high scores to their Facebook page. You said recommended. Recommended in what way? By Facebook or by Apple? If I do it the Facebook way with SDK then I can also use the FaceBook "F" logo for the image of the shared button and if I don't use their SDK then I can't use that "F" logo as the image for shared button? Do you know?

Comment: I meant recommended by me, because the SDK way offers you much more than only sharing content. But now that I'm context-aware, I'd use the way you feel more comfortable / simple or easy, so the SLComposeViewController. The use or not of the F logo is up to you, can use it with or without the SDK and you wouldn't get rejection. But with the SDK you could use the official button with their logo.